# Json for hashmap

Tags: json

I am new to json , trying to create a json workable for this hashmap:

```
HashMap<SomeEnum,HashMap<Integer,String>> agentNumbers;
```

So i created this JSON

```
{
     "agentNumbers": [
          {
               "Additional": [
                       {
                            "insuranceId": 111,
                            "agentNumber": "09090"
                       },
                       {
                             "insuranceId": 1111,
                             "agentNumber": "090900"
                       }
                  ]
            },
            {
                 "Full": [
                       {
                            "insuranceId": 1112,
                            "agentNumber": "090901"
                       }
                  ]
             }
        ]
}
```

When i do : gson.fromJson(....

It says :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 
BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 20 path $.agentNumbers[0]
```

Please guid me what i'm missing

thanks

Comment: What do you want to change hashmap or json

Comment: i wanto to change JSON

Comment: I am trying to find the mistake in my JSON

Answer (score 0):

I guess it'll work if you leave out the first index  `agentNumbers`. Something like this:

```
{
    [
         {
              "Additional": [

        //...

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"Additional": {
"112": "data2",
"113": "data3",
"114": "data4",
"115": "data5",
"111": "data1"
},
"Full": {
"112": "data2",
"113": "data3",
"114": "data4",
"115": "data5",
"111": "data1"
}
}
```

Try this

Comment: Hi @junaidp first of all create a GET webservice with your desired java object with sample data. Then you can  find out  the structure of JSON easily.

Comment: yes i am putting some dummy data in my hashmap and its working ., but json isnt

Comment: Ya. Just return that hashmap with dummy data in a webservice.

Comment: if i try yours , it says : Expected name at line 1 column 48 path $.Additional.